# How many triangles are in this figure?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

How many triangles are there in the given figure?

[image: Figure]

I counted 12 but the solution manual says 14. If you have any tips on counting triangles in figures like this please advise. I have to prepare for aptitude test.

Comment: Iterate over all triples of vertices.  If they form a triangle, count it, else proceed to the next triple.  In practice, it may be easier to actually look at each pair of vertices who are connected by a line and look to see if there are other vertices who are also connected to both of the endpoints of your original line.

Answer (score 2):

There are, indeed, 14 triangles:

[image]

Comment: Did you construct this by hand, or algorithmically @ParclyTaxel?

Comment: @DavidGStork By hand, in Inkscape (the same tool I use to draw ponies).